# firebase query not working properly and crashing

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I have finally got this query worked out(almost). I am reading the values of the array into a NSMutable array, then iterating over the array and finding the one that is == to PFUser(which is the object id of the user that I am trying to remove from the array)...Then I do a second query with the snapshots that I made in the last query to go straight to the path of the different locations and places the array back in to replace the old array...

```
     PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Recent", FIREBASE]];
FQuery *query = [[firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"groupId"] queryEqualToValue:group.objectId];

        [query observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

            //this is the -KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z
            NSString *nodeKey = snapshot.key;

            //the values are all of the key:value pairs within the node
            NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;

            //get the array from the dictionary as mutable so we can mutate is
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"members"]];

            //remove the object
            [mutableArray removeObject:user];

            //now build a path to write the array back out to
            //for the first node, it will be -KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z/members
            Firebase *path = [firebase childByAppendingPath:nodeKey];
            Firebase *pathToWhereTheMembersArrayIs = [path childByAppendingPath:@"members"];

            //write the mutated array back out to the same place it came from
            [pathToWhereTheMembersArrayIs setValue:mutableArray]; 

        }];
```

THE JSON

```
        "-KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z" : {
          "counter" : 220,
          "date" : "2016-03-07T17:43:37",
          "description" : "office",
          "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
          "lastMessage" : "AwEUcyXa0hgPxxAf3G1QjqhsNSv2nthtNBLFfD5WUydrMk0Vm2HwQlZUPyRTYOXZkW3+NCKY5/OM/5JBsn9+cQ7W/0rcFH4a75q2SNU8aaHnGw==",
          "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
          "password" : "XClOrgepBf",
          "profileId" : "MvKHg4Hh3L",
          "recentId" : "-KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z",
          "type" : "group",
          "userId" : "4nJOfpNDzp"
        },
        "-KBnmV52zFbMFKI1A9Ye" : {
          "counter" : 220,
          "date" : "2016-03-07T17:43:37",
          "description" : "office",
          "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
          "lastMessage" : "AwEUcyXa0hgPxxAf3G1QjqhsNSv2nthtNBLFfD5WUydrMk0Vm2HwQlZUPyRTYOXZkW3+NCKY5/OM/5JBsn9+cQ7W/0rcFH4a75q2SNU8aaHnGw==",
          "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
          "password" : "XClOrgepBf",
          "profileId" : "MvKHg4Hh3L",
          "recentId" : "-KBnmV52zFbMFKI1A9Ye",
          "type" : "group",
          "userId" : "BC8MRaq7Zl"
        }
```

I am confused as well on about how I did my setvalue...I need to do the same query that I did first, but I dont need to snapshot, I need to setValue of member where equalTo: is satisfied

Comment: I am assuming that setValue will simply overwrite the old value of members

Comment: That code is going to cause you trouble:  Your members array is loaded inside the block but then you process it outside the block. Your code is going to run faster than the values are returned so what will end up happening is that the for loop will be called *before* the member array is fully populated.

Comment: What do you suggest to fix this?

Comment: With the code you have, your snapshot will contain every group that matches the constraint, returned one at a time. You will know the specific path to the members node which will be the snapshot.key/members (like -KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z/members). The value of that node is the array of members which you can put into a mutable array. Remove the object in question from the array and write the array back out to that location. You can do the entire sequence within the block.

Comment: ohh so youre saying that snapshot is multiple objects. So heres the thing, members is(should) be the same for every snapshot and I need to record it down for another query. because I am getting the members, removing myself from the list then placing the new array back in over the old array in firebase

Comment: uh, no. I'll add an answer, maybe that will help

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help. Ive been stuck on this problem for a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this reduced Firebase structure

```
    "-KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z" : {
      "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
      "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
    },
    "-KBnmV52zFbMFKI1A9Ye" : {
      "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
      "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
    }
```

When you observe a node via a .childAdded event, each node that is observed (or queried with child added) is returned one at a time in a snapshot.

So the first node returned is

```
    "-KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z" : {
      "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
      "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
    },
```

Then the second node returned is

```
    "-KBnmV52zFbMFKI1A9Ye" : {
      "groupId" : "aVIweSJKwn",
      "members" : [ "pQJlYrHbq2", "PxOJQe8BdD", "4nJOfpNDzp", "BC8MRaq7Zl", "MvKHg4Hh3L" ],
    }
```

With each node you have everything you need to accomplish your task, which is: remove a member of the member array

So the code

```
    [query observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        //this is the -KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z node from the snapshot
        NSString *nodeKey = snapshot.key; 

        //the values are all of the key:value pairs within the node
        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value; 

        //get the array from the dictionary as mutable so we can mutate it
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"members"]];

        //remove the object
        [mutableArray removeObject@"PxOJQe8BdD"];

        //now build a path to write the array back out to
        //for the first node, it will be -KBnmV51zbE5kiHesc1Z/members
        Firebase *path = [ref childByAppendingPath:nodeKey];
        Firebase *pathToWhereTheMembersArrayIs = [path childByAppendingPath:@"members"];

        //write the mutated array back out to the same place it came from
        [pathToWhereTheMembersArrayIs setValue:mutableArray]; 

    }];
```

Comment: So I could just put this in on mine under where I initialize query at line 5?

Comment: Quite possibly. It may work out of the box but since I just whipped that up, it's untested. You will need to re-work the mutableArray removeObject obviously to remove your object instead of the one I picked etc.

Comment: Ill edit my post to what I have now with your answer plugged in, Im still having trouble, but I think it has something to do with my path

Comment: do I need a "/" in my path when childByappendingpath?

Comment: scratch that! I was a dummy and was passing it an object from parse intead of just the id that I was looking for! Thanks SO MUCH for your help @Jay!

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving an Android specific answer, but this might help you to solve your problem.

`setValue` just replaces the node referenced. So if you want to check if a data already exists in that node you'll have to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Which will give a snapshot of the node. Then you'll have to check if the data snapshot exists or not. So in case of checking a member where equalTo: is satisfied you need to go to that specific node first. Then add `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to that node which will give you a snapshot of the data over there. Something like this you can do here.

```
firebaseRef.child(member)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            YourClass mClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourClass.class);
            // Check if the data has the desired value and take 
            // necessary actions.
        }
        else {
            // setValue here if the data doesn't exists
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replace the node everywhere it shows up in that first query